# How can I create a pop-up box that I populate with data each time I call it?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I was wondering, what is the best way to create a pop-up box that has a header/footer that is fixed, and then I pass the data to (maybe a function?) it and it populates the box. I have a lot of different things on different pages that i'd like to have in a pop-up box (kinda like Facebook has) and the header/footer will always be the same, but the actual content will change.

What is the best way to achieve this? I currently have it working on 1 page on a PHP loop but I want to be able to have it on every page and want to know the best way to do this without making life harder.

**Here is my CSS**

```
    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 8888; /* Sit on top */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }

    /* Modal Content/Box */
    .modal-content {
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: 10vh auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 90%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
    }
    @media (min-width: 1366px) {
      .modal-content {
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: 10vh auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 50%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
      }
    }

    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
        color: #aaa;
        float: right;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

**Here is my table that contains the data and loops through my MySQL data**

```
  <table>
    <tr style="background-color: #a8a8a8;">
      <th>Sender</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    include '../../includes/connection.php';

    $mailResult = $mailSTMT ->fetchAll(); 
      foreach($mailResult as $mailRow) {
        $user_mail_from_id = $mailRow['user_mail_from'];
        //Use Mail ID to retrieve the User who sent the original message
        $mailUserSTMT = "SELECT `user_details_id`, `user_details_first_name`, `user_details_last_name` FROM `user_details` WHERE `user_details_id` = :id";

        $mod = "mod".$i;

        $fetchList = $dbh->prepare($mailUserSTMT);
        $fetchList->bindValue(':id', $user_mail_from_id);
        $fetchList->execute();
        $mailUserRow = $fetchList->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $mailFromFullName = $mailUserRow['user_details_first_name']." ".$mailUserRow['user_details_last_name'];

        if ($mailRow['user_mail_opened'] == "no") { $bgColor = "#d1d1d1"; $txtColor = "black"; } else { $bgColor = "white"; $txtColor = "black"; }
        $mailStatus = ucfirst($mailRow['user_mail_status']);
        echo "<tr style='word-wrap: break-word; text-align:center; color: ".$txtColor."; background-color: ".$bgColor."' class='delete_mem".$mailRow['user_mail_id']."'>";
          echo "<td>".$mailFromFullName."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$mailRow['user_mail_subject']."</td>";
          echo "<td><button class='button-primary' style='text-align:center; color:white; background-color: ".$mailStatus."'>".$mailStatus."</button></td>";
          echo "<td><button class='button button-primary' data-modal='".$mod."'>Open Message</button></td>";
          echo "<td>
          <a id='".$mailRow['user_mail_id']."' class='button button-primary btn btn-danger'>Delete</a>
          </td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        ?>
        <div id="<?php echo $mod; ?>" class="modal">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="contact-form">
              <a class="close">&times;</a>
              <h2><b>Subject: </b><?= $mailRow['user_mail_subject']; ?></h2>
              <p><span style="float: left;">From: <?= $mailFromFullName; ?></span><span style="float: right;">Urgency: <span style="color:<?= $mailStatus; ?>"><?= $mailStatus; ?></span></span></p>
              <br>
              <hr>
              <br>
              <h5>Message</h5>
              <p><?= $mailRow['user_mail_message']; ?></p>
              <hr>
              <br>
              <a href="mail?q=reply?id=<?= $mailRow['user_mail_id']; ?>" class="button button-primary" style="float:right;">Reply</a>
              <br><br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <?php
        $i = $i + 1;
      }
    ?>
  </table>
```

**Here is my AJAX**

```
  <!-- Mark as Deleted without refreshing the page -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.btn-danger').click(function() {
              var id = $(this).attr("id");
              if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this email?")) {
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "refresh_mail_delete.php",
                      data: ({
                          id: id
                      }),
                      cache: false,
                      success: function(html) {
                          $(".delete_mem" + id).fadeOut('slow');
                      }
                  });
              } else {
                  return false;
              }
          });
      });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var modalBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll(".button")];
    modalBtns.forEach(function(btn){
      btn.onclick = function() {
        var modal = btn.getAttribute('data-modal');
        document.getElementById(modal).style.display = "block";
      }
    });

    var closeBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll(".close")];
    closeBtns.forEach(function(btn){
      btn.onclick = function() {
        var modal = btn.closest('.modal');
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    });

    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target.className === "modal") {
        event.target.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: You can wrap all of your JavaScript into one `<script>` tag. Also, how are you capturing the specific data? Like, are items in rows in a table and you click a button in that row that captures that rows data?

Comment: That's it! This particular page is a mail system, so you click "read" and it'll open the pop-up box

Comment: So what you could do is declare a global variable, and in whatever the function is that opens the pop-box, find the mail object in your data using the id, then assign the value of that object to the global variable and then just have the body of the popup be equal to the global variable.